# How can I use Microsoft.IdentityModel to sign a JWT token?

Tags: c#, jwt, identity

I am attempting to write code to sign a JWT token using a private key from a certificate. I have been attempting to adapt [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44857593/13906087) (which uses `jose-jwt`) to use `Microsoft.IdentityModel` instead.

Having retrieved a `X509Certificate2` (called `certificate` in the code below), the following code successfully generates a token. (The payload below is a non-empty `Dictionary<string, object>`)

```
var privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var tokenString = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
```

However, an attempted equivalent implementation using Microsoft's IdentityModel doesn't work:

```
var privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey(privateKey);
var credentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

var handler = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(signingCredentials: credentials);

var tokenString = handler.WriteToken(token);
```

This code errors on the `CreateJwtSecurityToken` line with the error:

`IDX10630: The 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey' for signing cannot be smaller than 'System.Int32' bits. KeySize: 'System.Int32'. Parameter name: key`

Does anybody know what is causing this error, and what could be done to resolve this?

Comment: The certificate you are using seems to have a key smaller than 2048. Try generating one with a 2048 or larger key size

Comment: Thanks Alex, that has worked! I could have sworn I'd checked that already, but apparently not. The lack of a value in the exception message made me think there was something deeper wrong.