# Getting Exception while validating access token

Tags: c#, azure, validation, access-token

I am getting following exception.
I have use post method to get token using service principal
Message = "IDX10708: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string

I am generating access token using ""https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/token" and trying to validate that

```
            SecurityToken securityToken;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configurationManager =
                   new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
                       $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                       new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());

            OpenIdConnectConfiguration openIdConfig = await configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true

            };

            var userClaims = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
            return userClaims.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "appid").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

I am getting exception while validating

Answer (score 0):

Please try to validate the code by putting try/catch block and review the claims value in the debugger e.g. uniquer_name etc

you can follow this thread for more clarity:-

[When is JWTSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken() actually valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355384/when-is-jwtsecuritytokenhandler-validatetoken-actually-valid)

Hope it helps.